# How quickly can you type this string?

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a string consisting of only printable ascii (letters, numbers, symbols, and spaces), how many keystrokes are required minimally to type out this string from scratch?

That is, *current text* is initially an empty string and should end up being equal to the input string. These are the allowed actions and their cost in keystrokes:

- Add a character from printable ascii to the right-hand side of the current text
  (1 keystroke)
- <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> copy *any* contiguous substring of the current text to the overwrite-only clipboard
  (2 keystrokes)
- <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> paste the string last copied to the clipboard to the right-hand end of the current text
  (1 keystroke)
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd> delete the rightmost character from the current text
  (1 keystroke)

For example, the string "cbaabcbabaacba" can be typed in 12 keystrokes, which is optimal.

```
cba => 3 keystrokes
<copy> => 2 keystrokes
ab => 2 keystrokes
<paste> => 1 keystroke
baa => 3 keystrokes
<paste> => 1 keystroke
```

### Test Cases

```
cbaabcbabaacba => 12
ababcc => 6
aaaaaaaaaaaaa => 9
abcdefabcde => 9
abcdefabcdefabcde => 11
abcdefabcdefabcdefabcde => 12
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins!

Comment: Wait, `Ctrl+C` is two keystrokes but `Ctrl+V` is one?

Comment: @totallyhuman ctrl is still held down in theory

Comment: (1) Is the paste to anywhere or only at the right side? (As moving around the cursor is free for copy I would guess it is also free for paste, but probably worth stating definitively.) (2) Is backspace deleting of the rightmost character only, or any character again? (Also probably worth stating, the almost obvious, that backspace deletes.)

Comment: ...also probably worth adding an example (maybe how `cbaabcbabaacba` is achieved in 12).

Comment: @JonathanAllan See edits. Ctrl-V is only to the end, and Backspace is only the last typed character.

Comment: It is still not clear to me. Does "any contiguous substring" really mean what it says - i.e. that selection of any substring from what has already been created is free - or does `copy` actually only ever copy the entirety of the currently visible text?

Comment: Do you have any string where there's no optimal solution without backspace?

Comment: Suggested test case: `abcdefabcde` (which I think is 10 with `abcdef`, <copy>, <paste>, <backspace>).

Comment: @pacman256 In "`cba`, <copy>, `ab`, <paste>", it's impossible to keep holding Ctrl between `cba` and `ab`. It simply doesn't make sense!

Comment: @enzo  I could make ctrl-v 1 keystroke when you just ctrl-c-ed and 2 otherwise, but that might be too complicated.

Comment: @enzo you just copy, immediately paste, and then go back via cursor and type again

Comment: @JonathanAllan Any contigous substring not for free, for 2 keystrokes. It can copy everything, or just a portion.

Comment: `abcdefabcde` is actually 9 with `abcde`, <copy>, `f`, `<paste>`. Another test case would be `abcdefabcdefabcde`, where -- I think -- <backspace> really makes sense.

Comment: @Arnauld `abcdefabcdefabcde` is 11 with both backspace and no backspace.

Comment: @Arnauld Would it be more interesting if you had to find how many optimal ways there are or would it be fluff? Because I'm kind of convinced backspace is always unnecsessary.

Comment: How about `abcdefabcdefabcdefabcde`? But yes, backspace is useless most of the time.

Comment: @AlanBreadel (I meant explicitly the _selection_ rather than the copying itself) I have updated the wording in an attempt to make things clearer. Please check it over!

Comment: (Maybe backspace would have been more useful if the selection of any character, or perhaps even any contiguous substring, were also free.)

Comment: @Arnauld To my understanding, `abcdabcdeabcdeabcdeabcde` should make `<BS>` useful: `abcde<Copy><BS><Paste>*4` = 12; while `abcd<Copy>(<Paste>e)*4` = 14; `abcd<Copy><Paste>e<Copy><Paste>*3` = 13.